# Difference between ^ , $ and \A , \Z in ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

```
^ - Matches beginning of line

$ - Matches end of line

\A - Matches beginning of string.

\Z - Matches end of string. If string ends with a newline, it matches just before
```

What is the difference between the top two and the bottom two? When would you use one instead of the other? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: It's the difference between "line" and "string". It's important to understand that a line is terminated by an "EOL", which is something like `"\n"`, `"\r"` or `"\r\n"`, depending on your OS and/or the text you're processing. A string can contain many lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a multi-line string where `\A` and `\Z` become significant:

```
s = "this\ntest"
# => "this\ntest"

s.match(/^this$/)
# => <MatchData "this">

s.match(/\Athis\Z/)
# => nil
```

There are cases when validating user data that `\A` and `\Z` are **imperative**. For example:

```
if (site.match(%r[^http://sitename.com/$]))
  # ...
end
```

In this case an attack could be constructed around supplying `"http://sitename.com/\nhttp://evil.com/"` as the site string.

Comment: Indeed. See [the particular section on this in the Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions) for an example of using this gotcha for Javascript injection in Rails, say.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Sorry for not being used to Ruby, but it seems like Ruby's regular expression default has a multi-line modifier.  So in my examples/descriptions below, they will always act different with or without the modifier.  The `m` modifier in Ruby only changes the fact that `.` will match a new line.

---

`^` and `\A` both function the same **unless** you use the `m` multi-line modifier. Then, `^` will match the beginning of every line while `\A` will continue to match the beginning of the entire string.

Same goes for `$` and `\Z`. With the multi-line modifier, `$` will match the end of every line while `\Z` will continue to match the end of the entire string.

---

**Examples:**

I'm going to use the repeated string `abc`, and other character is an indication of where it matches and not an actual character in the string.

Without multi-line:

```
\A^abc
   abc
   abc$\Z
```

With multi-line:

```
\A^abc$
  ^abc$
  ^abc$\Z
```

Comment: unlike other regex flavors, it seems that the meaning of `^` and `$` has nothing to do with the `m` modifier in Ruby.

Comment: I had just updated my answer with a disclaimer, @CasimiretHippolyte. I left everything else the same in case someone stumbles across this and is curious for a non-Ruby answer.  However, tadman's is more valid.

Comment: thanks for updating it with the non ruby disclaimer. +1 still very helpful